# Doing some coding homework for computer science but cannot for the life of me figure it out

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Alrighty lets give this a shot.
#So it no longer works and i can't figure out why....

coach = 550
entry = 30
students = 45
maxstudents = 45
discount = 0
moneydiscount = 0
cost = 0
studentcost = 0

Run = True

while Run == True:

    students = int(input("Please input number of students going on the trip:"))
    if students > 45 or students <=0:
        print("Wrong number of students detected. Please consult your Principal or try again.")
    elif students < 45:
        print("Number of students =")
        print(students)
        print("The cost per student will be:")
        ticket_cost = (students * 30)
        num_free_tickets = int(students / 10)
        moneydiscount = (num_free_tickets * 30)
        cost = str(round(coach + ticket_cost - moneydiscount, 2))
        studentcost = str(round(5 + cost / students, 2))
        profit = (students * 5)
        #this makes sure it is in payable amounts^
        print(student_cost)
        print("profit is:")
        print(profit)
    else:
        print("This input is not numerical, please only insert numerical values")
```

it gives me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\littl\Desktop\Folders\Home-Ed Work\Computer Science\Python Homework Post- Summer\06-11-17\Students.py", line 28, in 
    studentcost = str(round(5 + cost / students, 2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

so i know its to do with:
studentcost = str(round(5 + cost / students, 2))

but because the line above is near identical and works im at a loss...

Comment: You cannot assing string to integer. Even though python is dynamic it has runtime type check.

Answer (score 2):

try using `int()` around cost and students. For example `int(cost)`. The problem is that students and cost are of type string, which is incompatible with an int without a cast.

Answer (score 2):

`str()` creates a text string, you cannot do math operations on that. You need for example an integer type. In your case you already have that:

```
cost = round(coach + ticket_cost - moneydiscount, 2)
studentcost = round(5 + cost / students, 2)
```

If you have text containing a number you can convert it:

```
some_value = int("1")
```

Answer (score 1):

High Level Answer: This is a type problem that can be solved by casting a variable to an int or float that can be used in math.

Since this is homework im not going to just hand you the answer.  But I found two problems.  First try adding a type print statement.

```
    cost = str(round(coach + ticket_cost - moneydiscount, 2))
    print("student: ", type(students))
    print("cost:", type(cost))
    student_cost = str(round(5 + (cost) / students, 2))
```

1) That should reveal where your problem is (it did for me).  You will need to add 3 little letters somewhere.

2) 2nd after you fix that you might want to check all your variable names for consistency. You will notice the error after you fix your line 28 problem.  Try and digest the error you got.

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

the / (divide) operand/operation doesn't work between a string and an int...Now look at the print debug statements.  Let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: I like the way you explain to people without actually giving the solution out directly.. Thank you Casey. you tought me something valuable about how to help people improve here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Python is dynamic and it does its best in order to convert int to float or int to long on the fly, but when you are adding str to int ("1" + 2), there is no way to tell if you want the output to be string "12" or int 3,
so the intentional decision was made to raise an exception in such case.
In your code you don't need to convert every intermediate result to str. Just print it at the end as is..

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
coach = 550
entry = 30
students = 45
maxstudents = 45
discount = 0
moneydiscount = 0
cost = 0
studentcost = 0

Run = True

while Run == True:

    students = int(input("Please input number of students going on the trip:"))
    if students > 45 or students <=0:
        print("Wrong number of students detected. Please consult your Principal or try again.")
    elif students < 45:
        print("Number of students =")
        print(students)
        print("The cost per student will be:")
        ticket_cost = (students * 30)
        num_free_tickets = int(students / 10)
        moneydiscount = (num_free_tickets * 30)
        cost = str(round(coach + ticket_cost - moneydiscount, 2))
        studentcost = round(5 + float(cost)/float(students), 2)
        profit = (students * 5)
        #this makes sure it is in payable amounts^
        print(studentcost)
        print("profit is:")
        print(profit)
    else:
        print("This input is not numerical, please only insert numerical values")
```

Comment: This is homework you should try to help him understand rather than just giving him the working code without explanation.

Comment: Sorry didnt realise..My bad.Will be more considerate in the future.